# Script that efficiently listens for changes in Do Not Disturb status

Tags: applescript, do-not-disturb

Is it possible to create a script (e.g. applescript) that would listen for changes in DND status and do some actions on each change?

Most examples describe how to change DND status but not how to listen to it.

Comment: I'm running 11.2.3. I mean the script should notice every time the DND state changes. Even when on lid close or open. I can get some info by running: log stream -p NotificationCenter --predicate 'subsystem == "com.apple.unc" and category == "dnd" and eventMessage contains "Setting"' -style json

Comment: Like muting alert volume in Sound properties.

Comment: I'm trying to work around an issue, when DND unable to mute alert sounds in third-party apps, such as slack or outlook.

Comment: Hopefully there is no way to achive what you want. If there were any it'd open up a  for abuse by 3rd party apps.